# Identities from the timelike geodesic equation

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, geodesics

Given that the geodesic equation can be written as
\begin{equation}
p^{\nu}\nabla_{\nu}p^{\mu}=0,
\end{equation}
where $p^{\mu}$ is the four-momentum. How can one show that
\begin{equation}
m\frac{dp_{\mu}}{d\tau}=\frac{1}{2}(\partial_{\mu}g_{\nu\sigma})p^{\sigma}p^{\nu},
\end{equation}
where $\tau$ is the proper time.

Comment: The first step is to figure out the difference between how $p^\mu$ is defined in the first equation and how it is in the second.

Comment: @TLDR, could you write out a solution?

Comment: Hint: The chain rule says $\frac{d}{d\tau}=\frac{dx^\nu}{d\tau}\frac{\partial}{\partial x^\nu}$, and the covariant derivative is  $\nabla_\nu=\partial_\nu+ ....$.

Comment: *could you write out a solution?* It is the policy on this site not provide complete solutions to homework-like derivations.

Comment: @G.Smith, sorry, but I still don't understand how the hint helps with the problem. Could you provide more hints?